# Regex in python splitting strings

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a string like this

```
SELECT [Orders$].[Category] AS [Category],&#13,&#10,  [Orders$].[City] AS [City],&#13,&#10,  [Orders$].[Country] AS [Country],&#13,&#10,  [Orders$].[Customer ID] AS [Customer ID],&#13,&#10,  [Orders$].[Customer Name] AS [Customer Name],&#13,&#10,  [Orders$].[Discount] AS [Discount],&#13,&#10,  [Orders$].[Profit] AS [Profit],&#13,&#10,  [Orders$].[Quantity] AS [Quantity],&#13,&#10,  [Orders$].[Region] AS [Region],&#13,&#10,  [Orders$].[State] AS [State],&#13,&#10,  [People$].[Person] AS [Person],&#13,&#10,  [People$].[Region] AS [Region (People)]&#13,&#10,FROM [Orders$]&#13,&#10,  INNER JOIN [People$] ON [Orders$].[Region] = [People$].[Region]
```

I want to get only Category and city dynamically without hardcoding the word . What kind of pattern should i use ?? So that i will store those two values in an array which is looped in downstream program .

I tried splitting the text

```
colName = re.split("\W+", result)

['SELECT',
 'Orders',
 'Category',
 'AS',
 'Category',
 '13',
 '10',
 'Orders',
 'City',
 'AS',
 'City',
 '13',
 '10',
```

it gave me the whole string , now do not know how to proceed . Can someone help ??

Thanks

Comment: So when using _findall_ and you get category and city, how do you know which is which ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use split, use `re.findall()`.

```
matches = re.findall(r'\bAS\s+\[(.+?)\]', yourString)
```

The words you want are in `group(1)` of each match in `matches`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response , it worked :)

Comment: I got only 9 colums but I have 12 columns 
I have edited in the question the actual select query . Can you please have a look . Sorry to bother ...Thanks What I did get was Customer ID , Customer Name and Region (People)

Comment: Some of your column names have spaces, my regexp assumed they were just alphanumeric

Comment: Thank you very much it worked , you are a great genius for helping others :) .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, seems you can simply continue with:

```
>>> category = colName[2]
>>> city = colName[8]
```

You can print to check:

```
>>> print(category, city)
Category City
```

Comment: Hard-coding specific indexes doesn't seem very robust.

Comment: You're absolutely right @Barmar, I just thought it can be a cheap solution for the example given in the question, which seems to be a fixed format query.  The regex in your answer is surely more reliable.